# My Raspberry Pi 3 shows the lightning bolt in the top corner, but I have a 5V 2.5 Amp power supply. What could be causing the issue?

Tags: pi-3

I am using the power supply that came with the system (mentioned above).  In troubleshooting, I swapped in a different power cord and get the same issue (the Pi runs slowly with the lightning bolt).  For example, the sound on the game I am running plays slowly when the bolt shows up.  It is inconsistent as well, as the bolt will show up for a second or two and then disappear.  I've tried a different outlet as well.  What could be causing this issue and how would I fix it?

Comment: cheap cable or PSU. Just because it is labeled 5 volt 2.5 amp does not mean that it actually is outputting that.

Comment: Very true Steve. I built a simple cable checker using about $20 in parts from amazon. It plugs into the micro usb connector and I can adjust the load from 0 to 2 amps. Using a known good USB power adapter, about half the cables I tested I had to throw out because they showed a voltage drop of greater than 0.5V at 1 amp. A couple had voltage drops greater than 1V. They would have easily triggered the low voltage indicators on the pi (both the red on-board led and the lightning bolt in the UI)

Answer (score 1):

You will see the Lightning Bolt Firmware Icon when your Raspi voltage drops below 4.63v

[Firmware warning icons](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/warning-icons.md)

Answer (score 1):

Test your system with my "rpiburn" program. It is designed specifically for power supply testing:
https://github.com/ronny-nilsson/rpiburn

Answer (score 0):

From what are you saying there might be two solutions:
1. Change the cable and get a good quality fast charging cable
2.Change your PSU and get a good quality adaptor.

The recommended PSU for pi is 5V 3A. So if you are using app that takes a lot of procesor can cause this too.

If you are using a lot of equipments on same plug that could also cause low powering.